# Application hangs only when breakpoint is triggered, .NET, C#, Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I refactored my application a while ago and since then I've been having problems with debugging using Visual Studio 2010.

My application works as expected while **not** debugging (not stepping through the application. An attached debugger does not cause any issues). However, when a breakpoint is triggered and I start to step through the app, Visual Studio and the app both hang after at most 3-4 steps.
To emphasize this point even more: It works well with my customers and regardless of whether I start it from Visual Studio or stand-alone - as long as no break point is triggered.
It does not matter where in the code I place the break point.

IDE: Visual Studio 2010 x64
Platform: .NET 4.0

The refactoring included a lot of cross-thread calls to `BeginInvoke` - all channeled through the following method:

```
public static void BeginInvokeIfRequired(this Control control, Action action)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.BeginInvoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }
}
```

There is not a single call to `Control.Invoke()` in the project.

- Is there something wrong with the above method?

Additionally, I'd appreciate any hints on how you would track down this bug. My current approach is to add output to the console and selectively deactivating parts of the code.

Comment: Hey Yas! :) almost certain that this issue is multi-threading related... do you have any sort of thread waiting/locking stuff that might be causing a cyclic deadlock?

Comment: @DarylTeo in the part of the code there is no lock. The only lock statement is executed right after startup

Comment: Multithreading, edit and continue. ThreadPools its a wonder it works(most of the time). Sometimes the complexity of the solution and code will simply break visuals studio. I've noticed that some third party components simply break this kind of code, It might even be some re-entrant code breaking the debugger etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect that in some cases the code you show poses a problem since `InvokeRequired` lies in case `IsHandleCreated` is `false` - it returns false even if you are not on the GUI thread.

For reference see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx .

The following code throws an exception instead of hanging... the fact that it "works as expected" when no breakpoint is hit might be a result of the debugger freezing all threads on hitting a breakpoint which in turn might lead to a different order of execution etc.

Altogether this means: you might have some "race condition" in your code where `BeginInvokeIfRequired` is called on a freshly created control before that control has a `Handle`. This can even be some 3rd-party code you use...

```
public static void BeginInvokeIfRequired(this Control control, Action action)
{
    if (control.IsHandleCreated)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            control.BeginInvoke(action);
        }
        else
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }
    }
    else { 
         // in this case InvokeRequired might lie ! 
         throw new Exception ( "InvokeRequired is possibly wrong in this case" );
         }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. That would only apply if I created a `Control` after initialization - right? Unfortunately, I don't create any controls at runtime (after `InitializeComponents()`). I just alter the `Visible` property

Comment: @yas4891 not really, even created control can be in a state where `Handle` is not yet created... AND some 3rd-party libraries (in past for example Infragen...) create invisible controls for internal use (like measurement stuff)...

Comment: I've added console output to the BeginInvokeIfRequired in case the handle is not created. I only get output during startup. I don't use 3rd-party libraries (except if you consider MSChart a 3rd-party lib)

Comment: @yas4891 yes - in this context I consider MSChart a "3rd-party lib" since it is code that gets executed which you did not write/don't have access to.